# How to find integer column in CSV file and also get sum of that column using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I am generating CSV files after reading records from database tables. To verify that the CSV files are being properly generated, I need to find the integer columns in CSV and calculate their sum to compare with database table.
I want to use Perl to accomplish this task as some of my CSV files may contain huge amount of records.
I am quite new to Perl, after searching I have applied following solutions:-

1. For getting sum of integer values in column used the command given below:

   ```
   perl -e "map {$x += $_} <> and print $x" < filepath
   ```

But this command gives only sum of 1st column in my CSV file. But my csv file can have an integer column at any position.

2. Then I tried following script:

   ```
   my $sum = 0;
   my $line = "111^ABC^XYZ^120000";    
   chomp $line;    
   my @fields = split /^/ , $line;   
   $sum += $fields[0];    
   print "$sum\n";
   ```

This script works fine when I replace `^`(caret sign) with `:`(colon) etc,but my csv contains data separated by caret(`^`) which doesn't work.
So can anyone suggest me a solution in Perl which can find position of integer columns in my csv file and calculate sum of those columns or how can I make the above script work for `^`(caret sign).

Here is the first few rows of the csv file:

"EMP_ID"^"EMP_NAME"^"LOCATION"^"SALARY"

"111"^"name1"^"loc1"^"120000"

"122"^"name2"^"loc2"^"24000"

"133"^"name3"^"loc3"^"55000"

"144"^"name4"^"loc4"^"30000"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caret is special in regular expressions: it matches the beginning of a line. To match literal caret, you need to backslash it:

```
split /\^/
```

For CSV manipulation, [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) is usually better if your input contains quoted fields or escaped separators.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me. Is this a good solution or there can be a much better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Things that can help you:

- the `-n` option, which will parse each line of a file
- the `-a` option, which turns autosplit on
- the `-F` option, to select a different delimiter for the split

With that in mind, something like:

```
perl -F"\^" -nae 'END {print $total} $total += $_ for @F' _
```

should do the trick.

Do note that you'll be adding every single column; it's just that some of them will be parsed as 0.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but it is only giving me total of first column's  value from csv.

Comment: Can you paste here some 3-5 lines of that file?

Comment: Hello.. I have edited my post to include some sample rows of my CSV file.

Comment: Your new values are surrounded by quotes; when adding, the fact that they all start with a `"` means that they are parsed with the integer value of `0`. You'll need to strip the quotes before you add them.